# Sequelize model associations for a scheduling app

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm working on an app that handles program scheduling for a large scout camp. The primary models I'm concerned with are:

Program represents an individual program activity (e.g. kayaking, mountain biking, etc. There are a bunch of fields on this model, none of which are relevant for this question.

```
var Program = sequelize.define("Program", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    max_participants_per_period: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    [...bunch of other fields...]
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Program.hasMany(models.ProgramPeriod);
      }
    }
});
```

Each Program is scheduled into a ProgramPeriod. A ProgramPeriod has a start and end time. Different programs different durations (some are half-day, some are full-day, etc).

```
var ProgramPeriod = sequelize.define('ProgramPeriod', {
    start_at: DataTypes.DATE,
    end_at: DataTypes.DATE
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        ProgramPeriod.belongsToMany(models.Unit, { through: 'Schedule' });
        ProgramPeriod.belongsTo(models.Program);
      }
    }
});
```

A Unit is a group of scouts and leaders. A unit will be scheduled into any number of Program through a ProgramPeriod. There are a bunch of other fields that are not relevant to this question.

```
var Unit = sequelize.define("Unit", {
    unit_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      unique: true
    },
    number_of_youth: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    number_of_leaders: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Unit.belongsToMany(models.ProgramPeriod, { through: 'Schedule', foreignKey: 'unit_id' });
      }
    },
    getterMethods: {
      total_participants: function() {
        return this.number_of_youth + this.number_of_leaders;
      }
    }
  });
```

Diagram:

```
┌────────────────┐                                  ┌─────────────────────────┐                
│                │                                  │      ProgramPeriod      │                
│    Program     │                                ╱│       pk: id(INT)       │                
│  pk: id(INT)   │─Program.hasMany(ProgramPeriod)───│   fK: program_id(INT)   │                
│                │                                ╲│ references Programs.id  │                
└────────────────┘                                  │                         │                
                                                    └─────────────────────────┘                
                                                                ╲│╱                            
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                     ProgramPeriod.belongsToMany(Unit, { through: Schedule })  
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                                                ╱│╲                            
                                                    ┌ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┐                

                                                    │        Schedule         │                
                                                              unit_id                          
                                                    │    program_period_id    │                

                                                    └ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ─ ┘                
                                                                ╲│╱                            
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                     Unit.belongsToMany(ProgramPeriod, { through: Schedule })  
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                                                  │                             
                                                                ╱│╲                            
                                                    ┌─────────────────────────┐                
                                                    │                         │                
                                                    │          Units          │                
                                                    │       pk: id(INT)       │                
                                                    │                         │                
                                                    │                         │                
                                                    └─────────────────────────┘
```

With this setup, I'm able to query for all the `Unit`s assigned to a `Program`'s `ProgramPeriod`:

```
Program.find({ 
    where: { id: 1 }, 
    include: [{ model: models.ProgramPeriod, 
                include: [ models.ProgramPeriod.associations.Schedule ]  
             }]
});
```

…and I can query for a`Unit`'s schedule of `Program`s:

```
Unit.find({ 
    where: { id: 174 }, 
    include: [{ model: models.ProgramPeriod, 
                include: [ models.ProgramPeriod.associations.Program] 
             }] 
})
```

I'm having trouble with figuring out a few things needed for scheduling. Assume that unit id 174 has 10 participants. I need to, for any given `Program`, query for all `ProgramPeriods` that have enough space available, and don't conflict with any other `ProgramPeriod` time already on the Unit's schedule.

I'm not tied to any of the above associations; I can change things around if it makes accomplishing this easier.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting question, I think of many ways to accomplish this, like filtering the total query or so... but as they don't have a bit of effectiveness I won't add them as an answer. Looking forward to watching a good answer.